# In what location does a .NET app look for .NET assembly file?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac

In what location does a compiled .net app look for .NET assembly file?

If the assembly file is not found in the application folder and not found in the GAC, where else will it look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably give you some info on the topic: [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to look at the details of the locations your application searches for a binding.

Comment: How do I get it to just display the bindings that are occurring.  I have turned it on to "Log all binds to disk" and the window is blank after I run a .net app. Why?

Comment: It's not a live viewer, it's a log viewer. You have to enable logging (as you have done) then view the logs. (Also, try clicking refresh). I find it's worth changing the logging path so you can verify the log files are actually being created.